# Do-while loop doesn't restart after meeting the last condition

Tags: java

I'm working on a homework problem where I have to generate a seed for random number generation. I'm using a do-while loop to ask the user again if he doesn't enter a number such as 0 or 1. My loop doesn't seem to reset while the program enter the else part (it just shows the println) and I dont know why?

```java
byte seedChoice = 0;
        do{
            seedChoice=scanner.nextByte();
            if(seedChoice == 0){
                System.out.println("Please enter a seed for the random generation: ");
                seed = scanner.nextLong();
            }
            else if (seedChoice == 1){
                seed = 1970;
                System.out.println("You are using the default 1970 seed.");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("You didn't enter a valid number.");
            }
        }while(seedChoice < 0 || seedChoice > 1);
```

Expected results would be for the scanner to ask a number again and restart the loop.

Comment: It's just waiting for input, no?

Comment: Welcome to the dangerous walking simulator!!
Press 0 to manually enter a seed for random generation or else press 1 to use the default.
2
You didn't enter a valid number.

Comment: But the printing of the prompt is outside the loop, so it goes back to waiting for more input without re-printing the prompt.  (Or at least that's what my reading of the code suggests.)

Comment: You're right I just didn't put a println after the loop restart so I thought it was still in the else statement. Question answered ! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Your code is waiting for more input.*

The printing of the prompt is outside the loop, so, when you enter an invalid number, it goes back to waiting for more input without re-printing the prompt.

To fix this, simply move the printing of the prompt into the body of the loop.